# Django: display textfield on dropdown select

Tags: django

i am doing an app in django for adding certain articles into the database. Right now i have it made so you can either select a category from dropdown or add a new category into a text field that is sitting under the dropdown.

Now i would like to change it so that text field is hidden until you select "add new category" in a dropdown. Is there an option to do this with django alone, without adding javascript ?

Comment: This is a server-client issue. If you want django (server) to handle you need a request to the server which retrieves the desired result. If it's only a client behaviour, it's javascript. This said, unhiding an element is not something to _ask_ to the server. Why do you not want to use javascript? With jquery is not more than a simple sentence.

Comment: I would like to avoid using javascript because i havent used it for anything in the app so far. Also online i saw some examples of django "onChange()" etc. which leads me to belive it is possible to do it, i just need some pointers.